Pardot form handler randomly fails to create leads
I'm experiencing an odd thing. I have a simple form that submits data to pardot via a pardot form handler. Sometimes leads are created and sometimes not. All fields name match with external fields on the pardot form handler and there is no errors when the creation fails. Has someone ever had that issue?
<form action="pardot_form_handler" method="post">...</fom>
